# Selectively build a module from a different kernel directory using Kbuild

Tags: c, makefile, kbuild

I'm having trouble in selectively building a module from a different directory using KBUILD.
I have 2 kernel directories
Kernel / kernel-XXX

Let the drivers directory structure be like follows

```
----kernel
|   |
|   |-----drivers
|       |
|       |-----boom
|           |
|           |----virtual_driver.c
|           |----a.c
|           |----b.c
|           |----c.c
|
|---kernel-XXX
    |
    |-----drivers
        |
        |-----boom
            |
            |---virtual_driver_XXX.c
```

virtual driver needs a.c,b.c,c.c for compiling.
I have an updated version of virtual_driver_XXX.c in kernel-XXX which also depends on a.c,b.c,c.c

How do I modify the makefile in kernel/drivers/boom directory to pick up virtual_directory_XXX.o from the kernel-XXX directory.
What should be the approach here.

The current makefile in kernel/drivers/boom directory is as follows.

## Makefile

```
obj-y += t.o

t-y   += a.o

t-y   += b.o

t-y   += c.o

t-y  += virtual_driver.o

obj-y += <...>.o
```

I want something like

## Makefile

```
obj-y += t.o

t-y   += a.o

t-y   += b.o

t-y   += c.o

if (a give condition)

t-y  += virtual_driver_XXX.o

else

t-y  += virtual_driver.o

obj-y += <...>.o
```

The problem is that I don't have a Makefile in kernel-XXX/drivers/boom since I don't know how to build virtual_driver_XXX using the a.o/b.o/c.o from the kernel/drivers/boom directory.

Comment: Is the separate directory tree a necessary part of this question? Could you move `virtual_driver_XXX.c` to the "main" directory and still get what you want/need? That might (though I'm not sure) simplify things here.

Comment: Are you asking for how to write the conditional? How to list `virtual_driver_XXX.o` in the makefile to try to make this work? Both? Something else?

Comment: I need to use a separate directory since kernel-XXX directory has confidentials that can't be exposed to kernel

Comment: Does simply specifying the full path to `virtual_driver_XXX.o` in the makefile work? (Forget the conditional for the moment. One problem/question at a time.)